# How to get my Bottom Navigation View to work?

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I am using the BottomNavigationView in my project and it works fine. Except I added the BottomNavigationView now on my 3. Activity and only there it throws an exception and I cannot find the problem with my code.

Here my code from my Activity:

```
private val mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener = BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
    when (item.itemId) {                                                            //when Bottom Navigationbar is clicked
        R.id.navigation_Auskunft -> { //Different Activities can be opened
            val intent = Intent(this, fahrplanmap::class.java)        //Opens fahrplanmap Class
            startActivity(intent)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_Abfahrtsmonitor -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, Abfahrtsmonitor::class.java)        //Opens fahrplanmap Class
            startActivity(intent)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_Karte -> {
            val intent = Intent(this, MapsAnzeigeActivity::class.java)        //Opens fahrplanmap Class
            startActivity(intent)
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_Meldungen -> {
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
        R.id.navigation_weiteres -> {
            return@OnNavigationItemSelectedListener true
        }
    }
    false
}
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.abfahrtsmonitor)
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener) //Here it is red undlerined with the error 
....
}
```

my xml file for this code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".Abfahrtsmonitor">


<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="360dp"
    android:layout_height="47dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="Suche"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="16dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="7dp" />

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/Recycleview"
    android:layout_width="370dp"
    android:layout_height="441dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="4dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navigation"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/editText" />

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="48dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="511dp"
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation"/>
```

and the xml file from the other activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".fahrplanmap">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigation"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:background="?android:attr/windowBackground"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:menu="@menu/navigation" />
```

In my other Activities I defined them exactly the same way and it works there without a problem at all.

I uploaded a picture with the error from the mouseover

[image: MY Error]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because you never initialized `BottomNavigationView` inside the `onCreate()` method.

Inside the `onCreate()` method:

```
BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
```

Then:

```
navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener)
```

Also, don't use the same id twice : `android:id="@+id/navigation"`

Here is a good sample of using `BottomNavigationView`: https://github.com/hitherejoe/BottomNavigationViewSample/

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked. I am farily new and copied the code I used from another one. I am still wondering why it worked all the time for my other 2 activities but not this one.
Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to hear that. Please remember not to using the same id twice. I've already seen such strange behavior from Android Studio too and it's probably because of added Kotlin which might have strange behaviors sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

I think there's a problem with your import statements.

It seems that an element with id `navigation` is found both in `abfahrtsmonitor.xml` and `activity_fahrplanmap.xml`. As both of them are imported resolution of your `BottomNavigationView` is not possible (resolution ambiguity).

If you need both `abfahrtsmonitor.xml` and `activity_fahrplanmap.xml` to be imported you should rename the element with id `navigation` in one of these files.